# Copying Rows from multiple sheets into another sheet with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to merge many sheets into a big one. This is the part of the macro where i loop over the sheets and try to copy the data from every sheet in to the big one.

```
 For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets          
        Dim lr As Long, rng As Range
        lr = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = sh.Range("A2:A" & lr)
        rng.EntireRow.Copy Bigsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)
                   
 Next
```

but i don't know why i can't copy the entire rows, this seems to copy only a column

Comment: `rng.EntireRow.Copy` should copy the entire row.

Comment: I know, but it doesn't

Comment: W/o your workbook it's hard, well impossible, to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

try my solution for Your case.

```
Sub MergeSheets()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws_BigSheet As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim lng_LastRow As Long, lng_LastColumn As Long, lng_LastRowBigSheet As Long
    Dim rng_WorkRange As Range
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws_BigSheet = wb.Worksheets("") '   big sheet name here
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> ws_BigSheet.Name Then
            lng_LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            lng_LastColumn = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            lng_LastRowBigSheet = ws_BigSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            
            Set rng_WorkRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lng_LastRow, lng_LastColumn))
            rng_WorkRange.Copy ws_BigSheet.Range("A" & lng_LastRowBigSheet)
        End If  '   If ws.Name <> ws_BigSheet.Name
    Next ws
End Sub
```